# Error loading external files with service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am using files by cdn, but apparently my service worker does not cache them. Would you do it?

[image: The error displayed in the console]

Service worker code:

```
const version = "0.0.1";
const cacheName = `sfa-${version}`;
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll([
          `/`,
          `/dashboard/`
      ])
          .then(() => self.skipWaiting());
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open(cacheName)
      .then(cache => cache.match(event.request, {ignoreSearch: true}))
      .then(response => {
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you tried to set the onerror handler on the navigator.serviceWorker container like this:

```
// no effect outside service worker script
navigator.serviceWorker.onerror = function() {...};
```

The error handler must be set from within a service worker script with self.onerror (self is a special variable/attribute here that refers to ServiceWorkerGlobalScope). The onerror callback is only provided an error message.

```
// inside service worker script
self.onerror = function(message) {
  console.log(message);
};
```

Alternatively, you could listen to the service worker's error event, which includes an ErrorEvent containing the location of the error:

```
// inside service worker script
self.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e.filename, e.lineno, e.colno, e.message);
});
```

for more detail [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736322/how-does-global-error-handling-work-in-service-workers)

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your answer correctly. What I would like to know is actually how and why it does not cache external urls?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736322/how-does-global-error-handling-work-in-service-workers