# catching exception thrown by service worker message event

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, service-worker-events

I can't catch an exception thrown by the service worker's message event..

The client uses following code to execute the command on the SW:

```
  import { messageSW } from "workbox-window";

  // .. code for Workbox initialization/registration omitted

  messageSW(registration?.active, { type: "SYNC" })
    .then((results) => {
      console.log("done");
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
```

On the SW (`sw.js`) side I have the following code:

```
self.addEventListener("message", async (event) => {
  if (requestType === "SYNC") {
    event.ports[0].postMessage(await longRunningTask());
  }
});
```

This solution works OK as long as the SW is not throwing any exceptions. Meaning that the client prints the "**done**" message after the long running process on the SW is executed. **If the exception is thrown nothing gets returned, ever.**

I have managed to fix the problem by doing the following:

```
self.addEventListener("message", async (event) => {
  if (requestType === "SYNC") {
    try {
      event.ports[0].postMessage(await longRunningTask());
    } catch (error) {
      event.ports[0].postMessage(error);
    }
  }
});
```

In this case - the result is always returned regardless, "**done**" is printed, but:

1. how do I actually produce an exception from the service worker, **so the client could catch and handle it**?
2. In general it would be good to hear if what I am doing is an appropriate approach to how asynchronous code on the SW shall be invoked from the client...

Comment: You might find this thread helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736322/how-does-global-error-handling-work-in-service-workers

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own solution I ended up using:

On service worker side - helper method:

```
async function replyToSenderAsync(event, task) {
  let isCanReply = event.ports && event.ports.length >= 0;
  try {
    const result = await task();
    if (isCanReply) {
      event.ports[0].postMessage({ error: null, message: result });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (isCanReply) {
      event.ports[0].postMessage({ error: error, message: null });
    }
  }
}
```

When exception is caught we set the error property. Use as:

```
self.addEventListener("message", async (event) => {
  const requestType = event?.data?.type;
  if (requestType === "QUEUE_CLEAR") {
    await replyToSenderAsync(event, async () => await clearQueueAsync());
  }
});
```

On client side request wrapper:

```
function sendMessageToSWAsync(targetSW, messageType, message) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (
      !isServiceWorkerSupported.value ||
      !isServiceWorkerRegistered.value ||
      !targetSW
    ) {
      reject(new Error("Unable to send the message to a service worker"));
    }

    try {
      messageSW(targetSW, { type: messageType, message: message })
        .then((messageResponse) => {
          if (!messageResponse) {
            reject(new Error("Service worker responsed with empty response"));
          } else {
            if (messageResponse.error) {
              reject(messageResponse.error);
            } else {
              resolve(messageResponse.message);
            }
          }
        })
        .catch((messageError) => {
          reject(messageError);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

The magic here is to read the error property and reject the promise if that is the case (hence causing an exception to be thrown). Use as

```
try {
    let response = await sendMessageToSWAsync(registration?.active, "QUEUE_GET_ALL");
}
catch(error) {

}

sendMessageToSWAsync(registration?.active, "QUEUE_GET_ALL")
    .then((response) => {})
    .catch((error) => {})
```